# How to get all items in a sharepoint list in a Word document and store it in a document library which has a template?

Tags: sharepoint, workflowservice

I have a custom list (Sharepoint) in my site to which a group of people add items. I have a document library which has a word template which can precisely store the list item from the custom list. I need to design a workflow so that I can get all the items added to the list every week (like a weekly report).

I need one document to be created every week which contains all the items which were added that week. I'm unable to proceed with the workflow design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your question, it would seem that you would prefer to to this using workflow but why not use event receivers attached to the document library which read the required data from the word document and create the necessary list item? If you need to do this in the form of a report, you could use Timer Jobs to do the same? Using OOTB SharePoint workflow to achieve this may prove more complicated than it needs to be. Others may disagree though.